# Display or Hide Div and change its icon according to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm literally new to Javascript but I've been trying to learn for the past two days and everything have worked out somehow until now.

I'm trying to create a hidden sidebar(div) that's displayed just after triggering a button and I have another one which is basically the same but instead of opening it, it closes it.

Both button are down:

```
<!-- This is one is to open the div -->
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="arrow_class" onClick="openNav()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right arrow_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>

<!-- This is one is to close the div -->
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeNav()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left arrow_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
```

Now here is the code for both buttons(one to open the div and a second one to close the div)

```
;function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
};

;function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
};
```

What I want is to have just one javascript function. Is there a way in which I can make the first button to change its icon and to change the functions according to the icon?

I know there's a way to change the icon with javascript:

```
;$('.arrow_class').click(function() {
    $('.arrow_icon').toggle('1000');
    $("i", this).toggleClass("fa fa-arrow-left fa fa-arrow-right");
});
```

(div displayed; arrow left; on click, it should hide the div).
(div hidden; arrow right; on click, it should display the div)

I hope I could explain myself clearly enough

Here are the three functions **again**(is there a way to mix these three in the last one to make it possible the icon change)?

```
;function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
};

;function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
};

;function openNav_closeNavFunction(){
;$('.arrow_class').click(function() {
    $('.arrow_icon').toggle('1000');
    $("i", this).toggleClass("fa fa-arrow-left fa fa-arrow-right");
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter into the last function with the state that you need. For example: 1 = open, 0 = close.

The functions may looks like:

```
function openNav_closeNavFunction(state){
    if (state == 1){
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }
    $('.arrow_class').unbind('click').click(function() {
        $('.arrow_icon').toggle('1000');
        $("i", this).toggleClass("fa fa-arrow-left fa fa-arrow-right");
    });
}
```

Now, the functions onclick in the a tags must have the parameter (1 or 0).

I changed the click event definition to unbind the event and prevent to through the function more than one time (this way you only declare one event)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there are some implementation mistakes in your code but as you are a beginner it's okay you'll learn how to avoid them later ;) I'll answer your question using your code:

HTML:

```
<!-- This is one is to open and close the div -->
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="arrow_class" onClick="toggleNav()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left arrow_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
```

JS:

```
var is_nav_opened = true;

function toggleNav(){
    $('.arrow_class').unbind('click').click(function() {
        is_nav_opened = !is_nav_opened;
        if(is_nav_opened){
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
        }
        $("i", this).toggleClass("fa-arrow-left fa-arrow-right");
    });
};
```

Hope this help !

Comment: It's not working, I thinks is because of the is_nav_opened variable is set to true and by default I'm hiding the div with CSS until the button to display it is triggered... I tried to set the var to false and yet did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle event and attach 2 function (open and close).

Don't change the CSS if you want to toggle, just add remove class - because you will struggle to revert the CSS back.

CSS:

```
.w-250{
    width: 250px;
}
.ml-250{
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```

Button:

```
<button class="toggle-nav"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggle-nav').toggle(function(){
        $("#mySidenav").addClass('w-250');
        $("#main").addClass('ml-250');
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-arrow-right').addClass('fa-arrow-left');
    }, function(){
        $("#mySidenav").removeClass('w-250');
        $("#main").removeClass('ml-250');
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-arrow-left').addClass('fa-arrow-right');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the hide and fadeIn effects

```
;function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width.FadeIn(1000);
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft.FadeIn(1000);
};

;function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width.hide(1000);
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft.hide(1000);
};

;function openNav_closeNavFunction(){
    ;$('.arrow_class').click(function() {
        $('.arrow_icon').toggle('1000');
        $("i", this).toggleClass("fa fa-arrow-left fa fa-arrow-right");
    });
};
```